# How can I restore my pretty Chrome colors?

Tags: google-chrome

It used to look like this [image]

After upgrade it turned into this:

[image]

I appreciate nostalgia but it's not 1999 any more. I applied the Breeze theme I found in the store so now it looks like

[image]

which at least looks like a something but it's still grey. How do I get back my pretty colors from Chrome 49?

Comment: What OS? For me, the colors of the tab strip are defined by Windows (and the standard setting is 'take a main color from the background picture on the screen')

Answer (score 0):

So while this seems to be a change in Chrome itself, apparently Chrome has Themes in its store and https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/classic-blue-theme/gapfoeoijjkibljnhednndeabimdilek is close enough. When you add a Chrome theme it gets applied immediately -- there's a setting to change back to "classic" or "GTK+" (I am on Linux) but there's no setting to pick between installed themes, there can only one theme be installed theme at a time and it's the active one.